Violation of i.i.d assumption in time series modeling
In time series forecasting,let's say you have
$x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_t$
and the goal is to predict the the value of $x_{t+1}$ given values at previous times $1,\cdots,t$. Let's assume that the value of $x_{t}$ only depends on $x_{t-1},\cdots, x_{t-n}$. One common way, that I have seen, to model the time series is to re-arrange the dataset to get:
$X_1 = [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{n}]$, with target = $y_1=x_{n+1}$
$X_2 = x_2, x_2, \cdots, x_{n+1}$, with target = $y_2= x_{n+2}$
$X_3 = x_3, x_2, \cdots, x_{n+2}$, target = $y_3 = x_{n+3}$
$\vdots$
Once data have been rearranged into the new shape, $D=\{X_t, y_t\}_{t=1}^{t=n}$ a regression model can be trained to predict the next value (step) of the series.
In statistical learning, it is quite common to assume $D= (\mathbf X, \mathbf y ) = \{(X_t, y_t)\}_{t=1}^{t=n}$ are i.i.d sample from $P(\mathbf X, \mathbf y)$.
My question is: If I considers $X_{1}, X_{2}$  or $X_1, X_3$ they are clearly correlated. Does it mean that the i.i.d assumption is violated? Do I need to refine the training set to get only independent samples in it, i.e. I should only keep $X_1, X_{n+1}, X_{2n+1}, X_{3n+1}, \cdots$ to make sure I am not violating the i.i.d. assumption?

My take is: While the i.i.d. assumption  of errors may be beneficial for showing optimality of a certain estimator (since it is a Maximum likelihood estimator then), it is not needed in OLS estimation, you still get an unbiased estimator. Just, if you accounted for the correlation structure, you could maybe be even better ... Happy to get some feedback on this opinion :)

You don't have any error terms in your model, and it is the error terms that are assumed i.i.d.

+1 jbowman, very important point

I don’t think it’s so common to assume the features are uncorrelated.

If you are doing regression on previous time-steps, why not just go the full way and use ARIMA? That's basically what it is - linear model that relates present and past. There is a lot of literature for it. You can also make it non-linear, or have errors non-normally distributed etc

Basically, if you are concerned about correlations, don't model your problem as set of independent problems, model it as time-series. The exact forumlation, ARIMA, INLA, some non-linear home-brew or even transformers, is next level question
